# Determine the first element and the difference of arithmetical sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Determine the first element and the difference of arithmetical sequence where the following is:
>   $$a_3+a_{10}=12$$
>   $$a_6a_{7}=18$$

I tried to solve it this way:
$$(a_1+5d)(a_1+6d)=18$$
$$(a_1+2d)+(a_1+9d)=12$$

The thing is that when I multiply the first expression:

$$a_1^2+11da_1+30d^2=18$$ This is where things get complicated...

Comment: Use the second equation to eliminate $a_1$ (or $d$) from the first, yielding a quadratic in $d$ (or in $a_1$).

Comment: Yeah, but a and d are multiplied together in the first expression

Comment: So${}{}{}{}{}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equation is
$$2a_1+11d=12$$
or
$$a_1=6-\frac{11d}2.$$
Substituting in your first equation
$$(a_1+5d)(a_1+6d)=18$$
gives a quadratic equation for $d$.

Over to you!

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: $\;a_6+a_7 = a_3+a_{10}\,$ because the sequence is an AP, and therefore:

$$
\begin{align}
a_6 + a_7 = 12 \\
a_6 \cdot a_7 = 18
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $\,a_6, a_7\,$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $\,x^2 - 12 x + 18 = 0\,$.